# Return all keys that appear more than once and have different values?

Tags: python, dictionary

So I have :

```
dictionary = {"John:"Legend","Ariana":"Grande", "Sam":"Smith",Ariana":"Smith","Lewis":"Capaldi","John":"Smith"}
```

So here I want to return "Ariana" and "John" in a list because they both appear as keys more than once, but have different values each time.

So far, I have:

```
for key in dictionary:
        authors.append(key)
duplicates = []
    for key in dictionary:
        if key not in duplicates:
            duplicates.append(key) # this is to find all the duplicate keys
```

Is this correct so far? Where do I go from here?

Comment: Your first dictionary will only be `{'Ariana': 'Smith', 'Sam': 'Smith', 'Lewis': 'Capaldi', 'John': 'Smith'}`, as dicts can't contain duplicate keys. Trying to find duplicate keys makes no sense, then.

Comment: If that really is a copy paste of your code, then you have some missing quotes. Fix the missing quotes and that line should give you an error. I'd iterate through your dict right after you create it and see what you're really putting in.